# How to change NSCarbonWindow visibility?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm using `::RunAppModalLoopForWindow(WindowPtr)` to run a carbon window as modal. But at some point I need to show/hide all application's windows with:

```
NSArray* windowNumbers = [NSWindow windowNumbersWithOptions:0];

for (NSNumber* windowNumber in windowNumbers)
{
    NSWindow* window = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] windowWithWindowNumber:[windowNumber integerValue]];

        [window setAlphaValue:CGFloat(showFlag)];
}
```

But window is `NSCarbonWindow*` that does not respond to `setAlphaValue`, and thus, the window is not changing its visibility.

Also, I don't know where `NSCarbonWindow` is defined so I can cast from `NSWindow` to NSCarbonWindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
if ([window respondsToSelector: @selector(setAlphaValue:)])
    [window setAlphaValue:CGFloat(showFlag)];
else if (showFlag)
    ShowWindow( [window windowRef] );
else
    HideWindow( [window windowRef] );
```